# Solutions of the LP problem

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

> I am asked to find all the solutions of the following linear programming problem 
>   using the simplex method.
>
> $$\min(2x + 3y + 6z + 4w)$$
>   $$\begin{aligned}
> x+2y+3z+w &\geq 5\\
> x+y+2z+3w &\geq 3\\
> x,y,z,w &\geq 0
> \end{aligned}$$

To solve this problem we use the Two-Phase method, don't we? 
Then I found that there are infinite many solutions, $(x,y,z,w)=(1-m, 2-0.4m, 0, 0.2m), 0≤m≤1$.
Could you tell me if this is right?

Comment: I think it is more than possible for a linear programming problem to have infinite answers. We're given 4 variables and only 3 constraints, which probably explains why the solution is a (4-D) line.

Comment: @2012ssohn Ok..And are the values that I found correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x+2y+3z+w \geq 5\\ x+y+2z+3w \geq 3 \\ \implies 2x+3y+5z+4w \ge 8 \implies 2x+3y+6z+4w \ge 8 +z \ge 8 $

so the min is $8$ when $z=0$

Comment: So are the values of the other variables,that I wrote in my first post, also right?

Comment: @MaryStar, ya , I think you are right.

Comment: Great!!! Thanks a lot!!!